# Generate "degrading" Markovian Time series?

Tags: time-series, markov-process

Any idea of how to generate time series with degrading markovian property.
It is easy to generate sequence with pure markovian property.
Here is an example :

```
dset = np.array(xrange(0,101,10))
np.random.shuffle(dset)
list(dset) * 50
```

In this sequence it is guaranteed that a state depend only on the previous state i.e markovian.

The question is how to generate sequence with say 90% guaranteed markovian property ? or 50% or 20% ?

The idea is to be able to test my models with different "markovian" series and see  how well it behaves and what is the critical threshold after  which the model definitely need modification or replacement.

.... looking for way to make it less markovian in a controlled measurable way ! if this is possible!

---

Here is my thinking, lets examine the two sequences below :

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 

1 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

The first one is markovian, because we can predict the next state based on the current state.
The second one for the cases of 2,3,4 and 5 it is markovian, but for the case 1 we need to know
two previous states i.e. non-markovian.

I want to be able to generate sequences where I can provide parameter that specifies the percentage (probably)
of the cases which are non-markovian.
(Currently this is the lowest common approach i can think of, but probably there are more complex scenarios).

The other way to think about is as way of testing let say Reinfocment learning. We know that it requires MDP i.e. markovian.
How would you approach a test of RL by slithgly relaxing the MDP requirments, by generating worse and worse sequence to measure
the degradation of algorithm or model performance.

Comment: What does 90% Markovian property mean?  If the time series is Markov then it has the property at all times t.

Comment: 10% of the time a state can depend on 2 other states ? OR probably easier 10% of the states depend on 2 or more different states ? hmm.. you right i have to think about better definition .... looking for way to make it less markovian in a controlled way

Comment: Have you constructed such a process?  Clearly it would not be Markovian.  I assume you are saying that these states occurred earlier.  Is one of them always the previous state?

Comment: Please define more clearly what you're seeking.

Comment: There are standard generalizations of Markov processes that may be more what you are looking for, such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_observable_Markov_decision_process)? (Your example could be formulated as a simple deterministic HMM, where the "hidden state" is just the previous observed state.)